# Tuple unpacking in argspec

Tags: python, function, grammar, python-2.x, argument-unpacking

I've used python2 for years without even knowing about this feature, but apparently tuple unpacking is supported in function defs:

```
>>> def foo(a, (b, c)):
...     print a, b, c
...     
>>> t = (2, 3)
>>> foo(1, t)
1 2 3
```

Defaults are also allowed, though they seem to be unpacked at function call time and not function def time.  And I couldn't figure out how to pass one/any/all of the packed arguments by name, maybe it's impossible.

```
>>> def foo(a, ((b, c), d)=('xy', 8)):
        print a, b, c, d
...     
>>> foo(0)
0 x y 8
```

This is not apparently not just a weird implementation detail: if you read the [grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html) carefully, in particular what an `fpdef` is, you see that function definitions are explicitly designed for tuple unpacking.

My question is, why was this a design choice and what is an example use-case where it's necessary?  To me it seems an obscure and error-prone feature that violates zen of python 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 17....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feature was put in as a natural generalization of the unpacking you can do in ordinary variable assignments. The feature is completely unnecessary. It was [removed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/) in Python 3 because it didn't add much and made introspection messy.

Parameters like these cannot be passed by name. The tuple parameter is given an internal name like `.0`, and the bytecode of the function starts out by unpacking any tuple parameters. While it's technically possible to do something like

```
>>> def f((a, b)):
...     print a, b
...
>>> f(**{'.0': (0, 1)})
0 1
```

, it's not really useful.

Comment: Thanks Kevin.  That PEP was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: One consequence of this PEP is that `sorted(seq, key=lambda (a,b): a*b)`, which used to work in Python 2.7, is now a syntax error in Python 3.